# don't scan the BLE already if connected while scanning

Tags: ios, bluetooth-lowenergy, core-bluetooth

i am scanning for BLEs in viewController.m

```
    - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    discoveredPeripherals=[[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
    _CBManager=[[CBCentralManager alloc]initWithDelegate:self queue:nil];
    NSDictionary *options=@{CBCentralManagerScanOptionAllowDuplicatesKey:[NSNumber numberWithBool:NO]};
    NSArray *servicesUUIDsList=@[[CBUUID UUIDWithString:IMMEDIATE_ALERT_SERVICE_UUID],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:TX_POWER_LEVEL_SERVICE_UUID],[CBUUID UUIDWithString:BATTERY_LEVEL_SERVICE_UUID]];
    [self.CBManager scanForPeripheralsWithServices:servicesUUIDsList options:options];
}
```

the available bluetooth devices will scan and i am displaying them by taking a tableView.

```
    -(UITableViewCell *) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell;
    CBPeripheral *peripheral;
    static NSString *cellID=@"Devices";
    cell=(UITableViewCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellID];
    if (!cell)
        cell=[[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellID];
    peripheral=[discoveredPeripherals objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    NSString *string1=(__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, (__bridge CFUUIDRef)(peripheral.identifier));
    cell.textLabel.text=@"LaTag";
    [cell.textLabel setTextColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text=string1;
    return cell;
}
```

if user selects anyone BLE, the connect method will calls and device will connects.by passing the uuid address i am connecting in another view.

```
  - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI
{
    NSString *tag=(__bridge_transfer NSString *)CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, (__bridge CFUUIDRef)(peripheral.identifier));
    NSLog(@"%@", tag);
        if ([tag isEqual:address])
        {
            self.currentPeripheral=peripheral;
            [self.CBManager connectPeripheral:peripheral options:Nil];
            sleep(3);
        }
}
```

the problem is, if i go back to previous view again it is scanning and displaying the previously connected tag. please help to don't scann connected tag.

Comment: I suggest you re-factor your application to perform your Core Bluetooth operations in a singleton class.  Trying to manage it from transient classes such as view controllers is much more difficult

Comment: will u help me how to retrieve connected peripherals. i don't know how to do this. - (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didRetrieveConnectedPeripherals:(NSArray *)peripherals
{
    
}

Comment: That delegate method is deprecated.  You should use `retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:` https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBCentralManager_Class/translated_content/CBCentralManager.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBCentralManager/retrieveConnectedPeripheralsWithServices:

Comment: will u please help me with code am new to ios. am not able to understand it

Comment: Sorry, this is not what StackOverflow is for.  You could try "post a job" over at http://careers.stackoverflow.com